# Create virtualenv in pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, pycharm

I am trying to create a virtualenv in PyCharm for python3.3
Here is what I am doing *File* > *Settings* > *Project Interpreter* > *Python Interpreters*

[image]

When I click on *create new VirtualEnv* I get an error.

The following command was executed:

packaging_tool.py untar /home/jan/Downloads/pycharm-3.0.1/helpers/setuptools-1.1.5

```
The error output of the command:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jan/Downloads/pycharm-3.0.1/helpers/packaging_tool.py", line 134, in main
    retcode = untarDirectory(name)
  File "/home/jan/Downloads/pycharm-3.0.1/helpers/packaging_tool.py", line 84, in untarDirectory
    tar = tarfile.open(filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/tarfile.py", line 1571, in open
    raise ReadError("file could not be opened successfully")
tarfile.ReadError: file could not be opened successfully
```

This is what it looks like.
[image]

---

How can I install virtualenv in pycharm for python3.3

Comment: Does that file/folder exist?

Comment: Yes just checked the `dir` does exist

Comment: Maybe this could be a Pycharm bug...

Comment: How did you fix this?  I have just setup pycharm on my el capitan mac am running into the same error.  I used pyenv to install python 3.3 and I am trying to create a virtual env for my project.